# Algebraic fundamental group vs arithmetic fundamental group

Tags: geometry, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to read about anabelian geometry and obviously the things to start with is the algebraic (etale) fundamental group. Every now and again I encounter authors talking about the arithmetic fundamental group, especially when they're talking about curves. Are these really the same thing, except the term algebraic fundamental group is used when talking about arbitrary schemes and the arithmetic fundamental group when talking about curves?

Comment: The paper [On the arithmetic fundamental groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0605) gives some definitions. There the etale fundamental group of an arithmetic scheme is a normal subgroup of the arithmetic fundamental group.